# Prove that for $ 2\leq p\in\mathbb{N} $ the series $ \sum_{p=2}^{\infty}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p}} $ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For any $ 2\leq p\in \mathbb{N} $ define $ a_{p}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p}} $

Prove that $ \sum_{p=2}^{\infty}a_{p} $ converges.

My intuition is when $ k $ is big enough $ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{k}} $ will be small as we want, and thus $ \sum_{p=k}^{k+n}a_{p} $ will be small as we want, and the series will follow Cauchy's condition and therefore it will converge.

I have no idea how to prove it in a formal way. Thanks in advance

I followed the guidance from the comments, have I done it right ?

$ \sum_{p=2}^{k}a_{p}=a_{2}+a_{3}+...+a_{k}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{3}}+...+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{k}}=\sum_{p=2}^{k}\frac{1}{2^{p}}+\sum_{p=2}^{k}\frac{1}{3^{p}}+...=\sum_{p=2}^{k}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{p}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{p=2}^{k}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{p} $

Thus -

$ \sum_{p=2}^{\infty}a_{p}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{p=2}^{k}a_{p}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{p=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{p}\right)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\frac{1}{n^{2}}}{1-\frac{1}{n}}\right)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n\left(n-1\right)}\right) $

which converges

Comment: it is positive so you can switch the order of summation

Comment: @BinyaminR And then what?

Comment: and then the inner sum will be a geometric series

Comment: @BinyaminR But we cannot change the order of summation for any positive series, just for the absolute convergent series. So in order to use your suggestion I'll have to know that the series converges, which is what I am trying to prove

Comment: you can show that the new series converges, and because it is positive you will get that it is absolute convergence. So now you can change the order and get back to the original series proving that it converges

Comment: basically, if  you have a positive series, changing the order can not change the result

Comment: @BinyaminR I edited the post, can you tell if I have done it right?

Comment: yeah, looks right to me. If you want a formal answer I would explain why you can change the order

Comment: @BinyaminR Ofcourse, I wrote it in my notes. Thanks a lot.